# TableView not reloading from NSNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I'm having some trouble getting a tableView to reload using NSNotification.

My set up is that I have a filter view which allows the user to apply filters to the table view, once they click to change a filter I am sending an NSNotification which is picked up in the AppDelegate, this then reloads the core data applying the filters as a predicate.

Once the data has been loaded from core data I post another Notification to the tableView which tells it to reload it's data.

Using NSLog's I can see that the notifications are being sent and received although the [self.tableView reloadData] is doing nothing.

Here is my function to reload the data:

```
-(void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"reloading table");
    [self.rootTableView reloadData];
}
```

Calling reload in the same way from inside the controller while it is currently in view works fine, so I'm pretty stuck as to why this isn't working.

Comment: So you're reloading while the tableview is not visible on screen?

Comment: Maybe. From the class reference I read that reloadData will only reload the data for visible cells...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the notification arriving on a thread other than the main thread?   It would be if the notification were sent from a background thread.  If this is the case, you'll need to marshall the reloadData call to the main thread.  Something like this:

```
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread: @"reloadData" withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, as the same series of events works when I apply the filter, but when i disable and go through the same process it fails.

I'm receiving this error though trying to implement your sollution:
http://pastebin.com/1m6wHF1g

Comment: Can you confirm if the notification is arriving on a background thread?  Are you sending it from a background thread?  To check, set a breakpoint in the notification handler.  When it breaks in the debugger, check to see that the thread name is com.apple.main-thread.

Comment: okay, then you have some other problem.  Do your UITableViewDataSource methods get called after the [tableView reloadData] call?

Comment: ahh yes thank you thank you, going through the delgate methods it occured to me that the array loading into the rows had been altered using my filter methods. But when i had turned the filter off i wasn't reloading the data set back to default, so reloadData was working fine it was just loading old data :D

Comment: This helped me. Minor tweak though, the first parameter should be @selector(reloadData)

Answer (score 1):

This is for catching notification. You can put this in `viewDidLoad`.

```
NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserverForName:kSFAccountsChanged object:nil 
                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                             [tblView ReloadData];
                         }];
}
```

The code below will fire a notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotificationName:kSFAccountsChanged object:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

Have you attached your table to rootTableView in interface builder?

Try adding

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.rootTableView);
```

This should not be null :)

2)

If you have attached correctly, can you post the code in your table view delegate methods to see what's going on in there?